# [Influx]: How to use Influx buckets with traditional script

Tags: grafana, influxdb

I am not familiar with Influx, although I am using it for one application for a longer period of time. I have a script that is sending telemetry data to a database on my own influx server that is version 0.8.
I would like to migrate/modernize it to managed influx on cloud or at least newer version.
I already installed newer version of Influx, but I see there is different logic…logic of buckets.
I am afraid, newer versions are not compatible with my script.
Before you can see part of my script with parameters to my influx server.
Is it possible to connect to bucket on newer influx?
Thank you for your help in advance!

```
dbname=“mydb”
dbhost=“influxdb.rogelj.net:8086”
user=“root”
passwd=“xxxxxxxxx”
```

I need to upgrade/modernize it, since I am moving the dashboard to managed Grafana, that is not supporting Influx 0.8 anymore.

I don't know what to enter as a server and I also don't have user/pass on managed Influx Bucket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of version 2 influxdb has changed some of its internals. It now uses buckets instead of database/retention-policy and tokens instead of username/password.

There is a compatibility API that allows you to call your influxdb 2.x instance using the 1.x API (I am not sure about 0.x but if I recall correctly the 0.x API is the same as the 1.x).

To use this API you will need to setup:

1. [`DBRP mappings`](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/cloud/query-data/influxql/dbrp/): these are a way to map a database/retention-policy to a bucket
2. [`v1 auth`](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/cloud/reference/cli/influx/v1/auth/): this is a way to authenticate using the legacy username/password instead of a token.

The only caviat I can see is that `v1 auth` is only allowen in InfluxDB OSS (the version you host on your PC) and not InfluxDB Cloud (the managed version).
If hosting Influxdb is ok to you you can proceed this way, otherwise you should consider changing your script to use the 2.x API (using buckets and authentication tokens).

Comment: Matteo, thank you very much for your answer. You're right. I have to change my script. Since this is not something big, I already change it and it is working now.